# Determine all places where I can place a basketball court sized rectangle in a polygon file

Tags: qgis, python, postgis, r, grass-gis

I have a polygon file:[image: possible_polygons]
and I need to find all those places where I can fit a `30 m` by `15 m` rectangle, without overlapping, (not necessarily those larger than 450 square meters, which may be `10 m` `by 45 m`). How can I achieve this, in any of the tagged softwares?

Comment: Does the basketball court have to be aligned N-S/E-W?

Comment: The angle doesn't matter

Comment: Have you tried doing this in one of those software products that you have linked to or are you looking for an algorithm?

Comment: I'm trying on those, but just cannot find a function

Comment: It can be countless number of them in one place that is large enough. Rotateyrectangle by 1 degree and you'll get 359 of them...

Comment: And you can fit a 30x15m rectangle into a 31x16m space in an infinite number of ways. Can you be clearer in your requirements? Are you trying to fit a number of non-overlapping 30x15s?

Comment: yes, without overlapping

Comment: you are looking for the [rotating calipers algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_calipers). This has come up several times in recent weeks in different contexts, it might be time to actually code it up for Postgis.

Comment: There is another implementation here, https://d3plus.org/blog/behind-the-scenes/2014/07/08/largest-rect/